# Determine in objects Array if actual object is best match compared to other Array elements

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin, data-structures

How can you determine whilst iterating in an Array if the actual object satisfies a specific criteria compared to all other objects within that same Array ?

Let me explain my question using an example.

Lets assume we have an array containing 5 objects of type Person.

```
data class Person(val name: String, val age: Int)
```

Now I'd like to be able to determine in that array containing 5 persons the oldest person in case there are multiple occurences of the name.

So in the example

```
val pers1 = Person("Jake", 22)
val pers2 = Person("Oliver", 25)
val pers3 = Person("Mark", 35)
val pers4 = Person("John", 35)
val pers5 = Person("Mark", 55)
val persons = arrayOf(pers1, pers2, pers1, pers3, pers4, pers5)
```

So having this array I'd like to be able whilst iterating through the objects to determine if the Person I'm evaluating in that moment is the oldest with that name in the whole array so that I cant act on it...

In Pseudocode something like

```
for(i in persons.indices){
person with non-unique name AND oldest in this array -> do something
}
```

Comment: There seems to be inconsistency in your code. you defined a Person with age as `Int` but initiate them with age as `String`. And the array is created with `empX` variables while you create `persX` variables

Comment: Do you want to operate upon those people who don't share their names with anyone else OR ignore them? Also, what is both name and age are equal for two persons?

Comment: Sorry Ivo you are right, was just typing a little too freely ;) fixed the String to Int ;)

Comment: Arpit : right now I can ignore them ! When both name and age are equal I'd like to operate on the first one during the iteration just to save time...

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, it is not possible to check against all items in the array at the same time. We would need to perform another iteration over all items, making our solution very inefficient (`O(n^2)`).

However, such cases can be very often implemented in much more efficient way. For example, your case can be implemented by grouping the list into a map:

```kotlin
val maxAgeByName = persons.groupingBy { it.name }
    .fold(0) { acc, person -> maxOf(acc, person.age) }
```

In simple words, it searches for the maximum age per each name. It results with:

```kotlin
{Jake=22, Oliver=25, Mark=55, John=35}
```

I believe it should be close to `O(n)`.

If we not only need the oldest per name, but we actually want to iterate over all persons, then we can start with the above code and then iterate over `persons`:

```kotlin
persons.forEach {
    val isOldest = it.age == maxAgeByName[it.name]
}
```

Note that in the case of multiple people with the same name and age, we may end up with multiple "oldest" persons of the same name.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easier to work with ArrayLists than Array and then this is what you might want:

```
val pers1 = Person("Jake", 22)
val pers2 = Person("Oliver", 25)
val pers3 = Person("Mark", 35)
val pers4 = Person("John", 35)
val pers5 = Person("Mark", 55)
val persons = arrayListOf(pers1, pers2, pers3, pers4, pers5)
persons.groupBy { it.name }.entries.map { it.value.maxByOrNull { it.age }}.forEach { 
    //here only the oldest persons of a name come
}
```

Comment: unfortunately I am receiving an Array from the API I am using....
So I guess I should first "transform" the Array to an ArrayList and then I could use your example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do at least one initial pass just to work out which `Person` is the oldest for each name - if you're just iterating over the array, when you get to the first Mark you have no way of knowing if there's another, older Mark further down the line unless you checked in advance (there is, oh hi Mark)

Similar to @broot's answer, you can do an initial pass to filter out the younger duplicates, so you just have one set of unique names:

```
persons.groupBy(Person::name)
    .values.mapNotNull { it.maxBy(Person::age) }
```

and then you can run your `forEach` or whatever on them.

If you do this a lot, you'll probably want to assign this to a variable you can iterate over, instead of doing it as the first step in the chain each time. Maybe a `Map` as a lookup table, if you need to check if a particular person is the oldest for that name (like in @broot's example) or if you want to be able to update individual names easily.

But with a `List` you can still do this:

```
persons.forEach { if (it in oldestPerName) doThing() }
```

and that's helpful if you want to handle those duplicate Jakes - should they both be counted as "the oldest" and have the handler code run on them? If so, checking them against the list of `oldestPerName` will match them both times. Iterating over `oldestPerName` itself will only give you one match per name

---

**Also** you might want to consider not using a data class. If another `Person` comes along who's called Mark and who's also 55, as far as the data class is concerned those two Marks are `equal` because their data is the same. But the two objects represent two separate, distinct people. If you put both Marks in something like a set, should it contain both of them, or only one? Up to you if this matters! Here it's fine (and allows you to do easy comparisons) but it's something to be aware of